# Object detection realtime using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

Im trying to detect objects in realtime using tensorflow. . I ran `jupyter notebook` in `object_detection` directory. then I opened the notebook file. It is firing the following error

Im getting the following error

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-7-956de605e8fe> in <module>()
----> 1 from utils import label_map_util
      2 
      3 from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

C:\Users\Documents\models-master\models-master\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py in <module>()
     20 import tensorflow as tf
     21 from google.protobuf import text_format
---> 22 from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
     23 
     24 

ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2'
```

How do I do object detection realtime using tensorflow in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little google search would already help or just reading the [Readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md)...

You forgot to run this:

```
#From tensorflow/models/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

Comment: it says `object_detection/protos/*.proto: Invalid argument`

Comment: you need to run it in the models folder where the object_detection folder is.

Answer (score 1):

follow readme in g3doc named as installation.md.

export your path by running command

```
"export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim" by being in research folder
```

# From tensorflow/models/research/

OPTIONALLY:
after running the above command you can try to run notebook from different folder by copying it to right directory such that its pointing correctly to utils folder