# cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2' ,even after run 'protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.'

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I didn't find any useful information from stackoverflow to correct the error, that's why this question is here.
I'm using tensorflow object detection .But getting the following error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sam.CP/PycharmProjects/Tensorflow/tensor_demo.py", line 20, in <module>
  from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
  File "C:\Users\Sam.CP\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 21, in <module>
  from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
  ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2
```

'

Hence i have done a small research about this issue and i found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45141231/10973854) and i used the `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.` command in cmd ,then the py files are created in the protos folder. I'm getting the same error even after the files are created.

Python - 3.6.0,
tensorflow- 1.6.0,
Protobuf- 3.4.0

Comment: It is working with Latest  `Tensorflow version 2.7.0` and `protobuf -3.17.3` and  `python- 3.7.0`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me is as follows:

If you are creating a **Virtual environment**:

Run the command after you create the environment to change the Google file `.protp` to `.py`:

`protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

However, if you are still facing an error, you can simply run the code on a google colab notebook:

**Protos Conversion to Python**

`%%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/TFOD1.x/models/research`

`!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

get the file in protoc folder, then copy it into the >models>research>protoc
And (import step):
Copy the folder to your environment path:

For example:

C:\Users\x04xx18\Anaconda3\envs\tfod1.x\libs\protos

This should fix the error for you!